# File copy error causes install to fail

Tags: system-installation

I spent most of the day yesterday trying to create a single VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 Desktop.  The downloaded ISO, ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso, was retrieved yesterday from Ubuntu downloads.

Out of perhaps a dozen attempts, only 2 attempts got past the copying files stage without the error below and two attempts the retry option worked.  The other 8 failed and the retry did not allow me to go on.

> The following file did not match its source copy on the CD/DVD:

The file that it errors on seems random - I never noticed the error being the same file from one failed attempt to another.  The error offers a retry button but only two out of dozens of failures did the retry actually allow me to continue; in all other attempts, I could not get past the error so I cancelled, deleted and recreated the VDI, and started over.

Since this is a VirtualBox installation using an ISO file, there's no bad DVD or CD.  The first time I got this, both files were on a spinning drive, both on the same drive.  After a few failures, I moved the VM and the VDI to an SSD and got the same error.  I next moved the Ubuntu ISO to the SSD so both the VDI and the ISO were on the same SSD and got the same error.  This proves the error is not caused by a faulty source disk or target disk.

One bit of possibly related information is that I use the VirtualBox disk encryption as well as Ubuntu disk encryption - something I have done for at least a dozen years without any problems in the past but any potential bug or error could, theoretically, be in one of those encryption processes.

I verified the sha256 hash for the source ISO file when I downloaded it and again when I moved the ISO to the SSD and the key matched the value provided by Ubuntu: 93bdab204067321ff131f560879db46bee3b994bf24836bb78538640f689e58f (Copied from output of Windows CertUtil - matches the value from Ubuntu)

Is this a known issue/bug?  Any help on getting past it?  12 attempts to get a single good install is just too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other same questions-answers, there are at least three possibilities, either it is:

1. because of corrupt ISO file, or
2. because of faulty target disk drive, or
3. because of faulty RAM.

For the number 3, solved questions before you did it by removing faulty RAM chip physically from its slot, provided that they use more than one RAM chips.